# Nested list of `[row_index, [elements]]` to Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a list as :

```
list1= [[1, ['dog', 'slow']], 
        [1, [5, 4]], 
        [1, ['mice', 'cat']], 
        [2, ['cat', 'fast']], 
        [2, [6, 6]], 
        [2, ['cat', 'mice']],
        [3, ['tree', 'hurry']], 
        [3, [7, 5]], 
        [3, ['mice', 'cat']]]
```

I would like to form a dataframe from this nested list. I expect an output like:

```
col0       col1            col2         col3
 1    ['dog', 'slow']     [5, 4]   ['mice', 'cat']
 2    ['cat', 'fast']     [6, 6]   ['cat', 'fast']
 3    ['tree', 'hurry']   [7, 5]   ['mice', 'cat']
```

Comment: Can we assume all rows have the same number of columns, and the leading index `[1, ...` is consecutive, and all entries for row 1 are contiguous? If not, you probably want to shuffle your test data: `random.shuffle(list1)`

Comment: Vamshi, per your comments below, never ever call a variable `list` (or `string`, or `dict`, or `set`, or `tuple`...) That shadows the builtin `list`, and breaks subsequent lines in an obscure, hard-to-debug way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an intermediate dataframe from the raw data:

```
first_df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
```

Use the second column as the data for the final dataframe by reshaping it into a three-column 2D array. Use the first column's unique values as the index:

```
pd.DataFrame(first_df[1].values.reshape(3, -1), index=first_df[0].unique())
#               0       1            2
#1    [dog, slow]  [5, 4]  [mice, cat]
#2    [cat, fast]  [6, 6]  [cat, mice]
#3  [tree, hurry]  [7, 5]  [mice, cat]
```

Comment: why `-1` ? ? ? ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a `defaultdict` (I assumed the `1, 2, 3`... etc was your index):

***Setup***

```
from collections import defaultdict    
dct = defaultdict(list)
```

---

```
for k, v in list1:
    dct[k].append(v)

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index').rename(columns=lambda x: f'col{x+1}')
```

```
            col1    col2         col3
1    [dog, slow]  [5, 4]  [mice, cat]
2    [cat, fast]  [6, 6]  [cat, mice]
3  [tree, hurry]  [7, 5]  [mice, cat]
```

Comment: I am executing it in Jupyter. It throwed an error  at `dct = defaultdict(list)` and the error is "first argument must be callable or None"

Comment: You probably have a variable named `list` somewhere.  Do `print(list)` and if you don't see `<class 'list'>` you have a problem

Comment: I am getting it as a list. but throwing an error at the same point.

Comment: @Vamshi Execute `from builtins import list` before the defaultdict line to solve the issue. In general it is not a good idea to use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: I used a different name "result" for the list but still it throwed me an error.

Comment: You already destroyed the original definition of the function `list`. Make sure that your code does not have anything like `list=...`, restart the interpreter, and run the proposed code again. It works.

Comment: @Vamshi if you ever lose the reference to `list`, you can do `list = __builtins__.list` to reassign it

Comment: I really like this solution, just one pedantic point: pandas allows non-unique indices (although hardly ever seen), and this will break in that rare case.